# Recommended way to perform operations on on-premises Exchange mail box

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

My question is related to the recommended way (going forward) to talk to on-premises Exchange mail box and perform operations on it from an external application programmatically?

1. EWS APIs and the corresponding SDKs look promising based on a few articles such as this :

   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/06/19/about-using-ews-and-powershell/

   but there is bit of confusion on whether it will continue to be supported in the future based on this:

   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2018/07/03/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/

   Although the above talks of just o365, the fact that EWS will no longer be invested in, raises the question if new applications for on-premises exchange should continue to use it.
2. PowerShell, remote PowerShell etc. also might work but it seems less suited for use/integration within an external application and more so for automating operations.

Could someone please throw some light on what is recommended way going forward to work with on-prem Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Microsoft GraphAPI.  Details https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer here.  Sign in.  Try the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages sample.  See more examples by clicking "Show More samples" on the left column after you login.

Is it The Way (tm)?  I don't know but is very cool.  I have some sample code I'm working with, nothing in a format to share, but look like the API covers a lot of territory.  Some client-only rules look like they need some work to expose, maybe they'll get beefed up in later releases.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question was more from an 'on-prem only' perspective. Aren't Graph APIs more of a solution for a hybrid kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of Application you are trying to write, EWS is going to be around in Exchange 2019 so it will work just fine talking to say 2013, 16 and 19 OnPrem. There are advantages and disadvantages to using EWS vs. the new REST API's but it is application specific and changing fast. But again it depends entirely on the type of Application you are trying to write and what version of Exchange you need to support. And typically newer features that will appear in new OnPrem versions aren't back-ported into older versions. So a great new feature that will work in Office365 and Exchange 2019 may not work in 2016 and you may need to use some of the older legacy API's to achieve the same thing. Bottom line as of today if you are an ISV and need broad coverage support for versions of OnPrem Exchange expect to need to use both EWS and REST. If you are just creating apps for one organization that's going to be migrating to 2019 in the future you'll probably get away with just REST.

Comment: Thanks Glen. My question was coming from the other way round. Basically, 1. An EWS Api that works on, say, 2013 will continue to work on 2019. 2. A new feature on 2019 will have support in EWS, even if just for that version. To me 1 seems likely but given that EWS will no longer be enhanced 2 seems unlikely. Also, when you refer to the new REST APIs what APIs are you referring to? Most of what I have read about new APIs talk about hybrid setups or o365 only.

Comment: 1. Yes EWS will be fully supported on 2019, however how you do authentication may change. With the current issues in Basic auth this is going to be an increasing sticking point for companies. 2. New feature in Mail are generally client driven but it really depends on what your app is and what it does, underlying access to a Mailbox remain unchanged in EWS in 2019 and is actually better then what you can do in the Graph or REST currently (eg the Graph doesn't give the ability to access hidden items and folders etc). The REST API's are the Graph and outlook endpoint but need Hybrid etc.

Comment: Thanks Glen. Your response was very useful - unfortunately my upvote does not count :) . I hope MS would add an official note somewhere about the direction for EWS APIs for on-premises - or maybe one exists and I did not find it. Most documents seem to talk about cloud \ hybrid only.